# Next and Previous buttons are not showing on home page for post

Tags: posts, wp-query

I made a theme from PSD to WordPress but the "next"-"previous" buttons are not showing on home page.

Here is the code of `single.php`:

```
    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <nav class="nav-single">

                    <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'aquaponicfamily' ); ?></h3>
                    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'aquaponicfamily' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?></span>
                    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'aquaponicfamily' ) . '</span>' ); ?></span>
                </nav><!-- .nav-single -->

                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What the changes are required?

Comment: For Home page content, single.php is not responsible. Please change the code block with `index.php` or `front-page.php` codes.

Answer (score 0):

like @Mayeennul said you have your templates mixed up. Generally speaking the home page contains a list of excerpts `the_excerpt()` with links to individual blog posts that are displayed using single.php.

If you want a single blog post as your home page you could copy single.php and rename it to index.php or front-page.php.